# WS SOAP Security Header Error

Tags: php, web-services, wso2

I am trying to secure SOAP requests using WSO2's Web Services Framework for PHP.

Here is my request:

```
$reqPayloadString = <<<XML
       <echo>
       <echoRequest>TEST</echoRequest>
       </echo>
XML;


$reqMessage = new WSMessage($reqPayloadString,
                                array("to" => "http://localhost/service/echo",
                                      "action" => "echo"));

$sec_token = new WSSecurityToken(array("user" => "myusername",
                                       "password" => "mypassword",
                                       "passwordType" => "Digest"));  

$client = new WSClient(array("useWSA" => TRUE,
                             "policy" => new WSPolicy(file_get_contents("policy.xml")),
                             "securityToken" => $sec_token));

$resMessage = $client->request($reqMessage);
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Missing wsse:Security header in request
```

How should I set  the `wsse:Security` header in the request above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to solve this unfortunately. I have tried the tips suggest by @Peter in his response.

I am now using [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) and native Java classes to make the secure request.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add "ttl" => 300 in the WSSecurityToken constructor since you are not using WSPolicy with an array, but with a policy file. So your code should look like this:

```
$sec_token = new WSSecurityToken(array("user" => "myusername", 
                                       "password" => "mypassword", 
                                       "passwordType" => "Digest", 
                                       "ttl" => 300 ));
```

At least this is what chapter 8.1 of the manual states: http://wso2.org/project/wsf/php/2.1.0/docs/security_manual.html#1

> If you want to have the UsernameToken, then the user, password and passwordType (optional) options must be set. For TimeStamp, the ttl option must be set.

Some additional info:

Your passwordType is Digest, this means that the receiver needs both wsse:Nonce and wsu:Created (timestamp) to be available in the header. If you use passwordType is Text, then you do not need to specify ttl, since you do not need both elements mentioned in that case.

I am not sure though whether the PHP WSSecurityToken class takes care of adding the wsse:Nonce. Could be that it is handled based on the policy provided.

Anyway, your policy should look something like this in case of Digest:

```
<sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:HashPassword/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:UsernameToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SupportingTokens>
```

source: http://blog.rampartfaq.com/2009/08/how-to-ask-for-hashed-password-in.html

Note: I have not tried it (yet). I never used WSO2's Web Services Framework for PHP.

Comment: Thank you, nice response +1. However, I am still receiving the same error. I currently looking at alternatives such as PHP/Java Bridge to remove the need for the WS02 framework and use native Java to secure the requests. Thanks again.